# Write a trigger to update the columnB in TableB when the ColumnA in TableA are updated based on the common column in both the tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[USERS]
(
    [USER_NAME] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [EMAIL_ADDRESS] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [REGISTERED_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [FULL_NAME] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [MANAGER] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
    [DEPARTMENT] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [TITLE] [nvarchar](64) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([USER_NAME] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This is my table and I want the trigger to fire when the manager column is updated and the same values of the manage have to update on the another table based on the `USER_NAME` column.

i tried the the below trigger but it is not working.

```
Create TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateManager]
ON  [dbo].[USERS]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @USER_NAME as nvarchar   
declare @MANAGER as nvarchar
if(update(MANAGER))
begin
    select @USER_NAME = USER_NAME from deleted
    select @manager = Manager from deleted 
    update [dbo].[USERS_TEST] set MANAGER=@MANAGER where USER_NAME=  @USER_NAME     

end

END
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select from `Deleted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. They way you've defined your `@User_Name` and `@Manager` variables right now - they're **exactly ONE character** long ....

Answer (score 0):

You have two MAJOR issues in your trigger:

- As mentioned in a comment, `deleted` can have multiple rows and you don't take that into account.
- `nvarchar` has no length; the default in this case is a length of 1.

I suspect that the query you want is:

```
update ut
    set MANAGER = d.MANAGER 
    from [dbo].[USERS_TEST] ut join
         deleted d
         on ut.USER_NAME = d.USER_NAME  ;
```